# Test Class for Scheduled Flow

Tags: unit-test, visual-workflow, scheduled

I'm trying to write a Test class to test a Scheduled flow. However I'm not sure how to call this flow. :/

I've tried the following on the my testMethod

```
@isTest
    static void testMethod1(){
    Test.startTest();
    Flow.Interview myFlow = flow.Interview.createInterview('Flow Name', New Map<String,string>());
    myFlow.start();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
FATAL_ERROR System.FlowException: The flow failed to start because the provided values were not valid: 
You can't launch a schedule-triggered flow by clicking Run in Flow Builder. To test this flow, 
click Debug and then Run. To launch this flow, activate the flow and wait until the scheduled time.
```

Has anyone found a way of testing a scheduled flow?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to test this flow? I'm pretty sure you can't, but I'd be interested in your use case.

Comment: Would be for regression testing basically, to pick if any org chance could break this flow. 
Since we can test an automated flow, or a scheduled apex class, I was wondering if we could test a scheduled flow as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate your flow as an auto-launched one and use the scheduled flow only for the scheduling of the flow.

This way you can test the logic in the Auto-Launched flow by mocking the scheduled flow conditions and start the flow with code.

You can also create another auto-launched flow that is triggered by the schedule to create a logfile externally or as a record to see if the scheduling is working (Heartbeat style)

To my current knowledge there is no way to test the scheduling itself.